Proving $0x+0y=0xy$ in a wheel.
This appears to be new to MSE.
The Question:

Show that, in a wheel $W$, $0x+0y=0xy$ for all $x,y\in W$.

Motivation:
I'd like to learn more about wheel theory, so I looked at the Wikipedia page and found the statement above.
The Definition:
A wheel is an algebraic structure $(W,0,1,+,\cdot, /)$ where:

$W$ is a set,
$0,1\in W,$
$+$ and $\cdot$ are binary operations,
$/$ is a unary operation,

and

$+,\cdot$ are associative, commutative, and with identities $0$ and $1$, respectively,
$//x=x$,
$/(xy)=/x/y$,
$xz+yz=(x+y)z+0z$,
$(x+yz)/y=x/y+z+0y$,
$0\cdot 0=0$,
$(x+0y)z=xz+0y$,
$/(x+0y)=/x+0y$,
$0/0+x=0/0$.

We denote $0/0$ by $\bot$.
The final axiom can be written as
$$\bot+x=\bot.$$
An Attempt:
Let $x,y\in W$. Then
$$\begin{align}
0x+0y&=x0+y0\\
&=(x+y)0+0\cdot 0\\
&=(x+y)0+0\\
&=(x+y)0\\
&=(x+y\cdot 1)0\\
&=x/y+1+0y.
\end{align}$$
That's about as far as I got.
Another thought is, perhaps, exploiting $//(xy)=xy$ by adding it to and subtracting it from the LHS, but that isn't fully formed.

Yes, I notice the misapplication of the axiom in hindsight. Sorry!

One of the axioms of a wheel, according to Wikipedia, is $(x + 0y)z = xz + 0y$. Substituting $x = 0$, we get $$0z + 0y = (0 + 0y)z = 0yz = 0zy,$$ as $0$ is the additive identity, and multiplication is associative and commutative (or addition is commutative).
